# why hasAttribute give false value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do same functionality as jquery.I have a one line in jquery it gives me `true` and same thing I am checking using `javascript` it gives me `false`.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/rixanoxiji/2/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$(function(){
  $('.abc').is('div[data-type]')
  console.log($('.abc').is('div[data-type]'))

console.log(document.querySelector('.abc').hasAttribute('div[data-type]'))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the "div" part in the `hasAttribute` function's parameter in order to work it in JavaScript

```js
$(function(){
  $('.abc').is('div[data-type]')
  console.log($('.abc').is('div[data-type]'))

console.log(document.querySelector('.abc').hasAttribute('data-type'))
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bcembed abc bcsingle" data-bcid="sss" data-type="single" data-autoplay="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```